# svm loss function gradient

Tags: svm, gradient-descent, loss-functions, gradient

I was taking Stanford's [cs231n](https://cs231n.github.io) class and was unable to understand the gradient calculated using the SVM loss function.

You should go [here](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/#computing-the-gradient-analytically-with-calculus) to check the notes which I am talking about.

This is the SVM loss function.
[image: SVM LOSS FUNCTION]

And now we want to find it's gradients.
With respect to the weights of the correct class, the gradient of the loss function will be,
[image: GRADIENT WITH RESPECT TO CORRECT CLASSES]
**Until Now I understand Everything, the problem occurs in finding the gradient with respect to the incorrect classes :**

[image: GRADIENT WITH RESPECT TO INCORRECT CLASSES]

I do not understand the calculation of this gradient, where did the **Sigma** go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the derivative wrt some $k\neq y_i$, the $w_k$ appears in the whole expression *just once*, i.e. when $j=k$. And, the gradient will be just $x_i$ times the indicator.

For example, let the set $j\neq y_i$ be $\{a,b,k\}$. The expanded version of the loss function will be 
$$L_i=\max(0,w_ax_i-w_{y_i}x_i+\Delta)+\max(0,w_bx_i-w_{y_i}x_i+\Delta)+\max(0,w_kx_i-w_{y_i}x_i+\Delta)$$

If you take the derivative with respect to $w_k$, you'll have just one indicator function, leaving you with no sigma expression.

Comment: Okay so are you saying that when we are talking about **'derivative of L(sub)i w.r.t a particular  class j'**, only one term remains because other classes with **'w(sub)j'** will be denoting different classes rather than that same **'j th'** class whose respect to we are differentiating.                    **I know I have phrased this poorly but I hope you get me, o/w I'll try and rephrase this some other way, Thanks**

Comment: Yes, exactly, you put it right.

Comment: Thanks a ton man.